# Hide image when hovering another image

Tags: javascript, css

I can't seem to get this working , so don't know if its possible

When i hover over the img.helmet , i want the img.icon to be hidden

```
  <img class="helmet" src="">
  <img class="mini" src="">        
  <img class="helmet" src="">
  <img class="mini" src="">
  <img class="icon" src="">
```

Here is my jsfiddle attempt - http://jsfiddle.net/8wrbL/28/

```
.helmet:hover > .icon,.helmet:hover + .icon {
  display:none;z-index:-999999;left:-999999;
}
```

Updated: appears this works , but seems like a lot a css for a simple task , i'll have a lot of images and this way might take some time

```
.helmet:hover+.mini+.icon,.helmet:hover+.mini+.helmet+.mini+.icon,.helmet:hover+.mini+.helmet+.mini+.helmet+.mini+.icon{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem purely using CSS?  Or are you able to use JavaScript?

Comment: i can use javascript if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try targeting it with jQuery and using the class as a way to hide it.

**jQuery**

```
$('.helmet').hover(function () {
   $('.icon').toggleClass('hidden'); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.icon.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/8wrbL/48/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you simply use the hide and show of Jquery :: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp